# Passing and return value of external function in awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I am calling function from another script from awk.

1. Why i need to press enter even after adding /dev/null
2. Why the passed argument is not displayed. I am getting spaces.
3. I am not getting the return value from external function.

---

```
cat mainpgm.sh
#!/bin/bash
key="09"
awk -v dk="$key" ' { ma = system(". /home/ott/functions.sh;derived dk")</dev/null ; "print returned value" ma } '


cat functions.sh
#!/bin/bash
derived () {
echo "outside function" $dk
return 9
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `awk` in the first place? If you just want to call a script, there's no need for it. The purpose of `awk` is to read input and transform it.

Comment: I am comparing two files. So using awk.

Comment: OK,if you're comparing 2 files then why are you using shell instead of doing it all in awk? You seem extremely confused about what awk and shell are individually and the relationship between them. If you explain what it is you're trying to DO instead of asking us for help to implement what you think is the solution (aka the XY problem, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), we can probably be of much more help.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to process input in `awk`, redirect its input to `/dev/null`, and do everything in the `BEGIN` block. Also, for the `dk` variable to be replaced with its value, it has to be outside the quotes.

```
awk -v dk="$key" 'BEGIN { 
    ma = system(". /home/ott/functions.sh;derived " dk); 
    print "returned value", ma 
}' < /dev/null
```

To answer your questions:

1. You put `/dev/null` in the wrong place. It's supposed to be the input of the script, not the `system` function.
2. Two reasons: First, you put `dk` inside the quotes, so its value is not substituted. Second, the `derived` function doesn't print its argument, it prints `$dk`, which is a nonexistent shell variable. The argument to a function is `$1`, so it should do:

   ```
   echo "outside function $1"
   ```
3. You had `print` inside the quotes, so it wasn't being executed as a statement.

Comment: Cant i use this outside BEGIN. I will be passing argument based on file columns

Comment: You asked how to not have to type Enter, that's my answer. If you'll be giving it a file to read, then you won't have to type Enter, because it will read from the file instead of the terminal.

Comment: @Barmar.Thanks for your suggestion. My function call is based on i/p values. My code will roughly look like `cat mainpgm.sh
#!/bin/bash
key="09"
awk -v dk="$key" ' { 
if $0 == "mandate"
{
ma = system(". /home/ott/functions.sh;derived " dk</dev/null ;
 "print returned value" ma
if ma <0
--do some action
}
else
{
--call another function
 } IN1`

Comment: @Barmar you can also pass an empty here string i.e `<<< ""`